# Python 3.2 Cx_Freeze won't compile whole tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, tkinter, cx-freeze

I've made this little calculator which I tried compliling with cx_freeze. It calculates something and gives you the answer in messagebox. Works all fine when I run it from IDLE, but when I run it from .exe, it opens the GUI created with Tkinter, but if I press my calculate button, which should pop up the messagebox, it gives me following error in dos shell:

'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1399, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "calculator1.pyw", line 46, in energyKinetic
NameError: global name 'messagebox' is not defined'

I use the following 'setup.py':

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


setup(
    name = 'Kinetic Energy Calculator',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Calculate',
    executables = [Executable('calculator1.pyw')],
)
```

and run it with 'C:\Python32>python setup.py build' from cmd.

The code for calculator itself is just siple Tkinter GUI, with buttons, labels, entries, and messageboxes, so I don't see a reson for posting it here, unless of course someone will find it necessery for me to do so.
So, is there anything important I didn't put in the setup.py for it to compile correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create custom messageboxes with tkinter windows, as the actual ones somehow don't exist when trying to launch a program other than hitting the F5 button. In other words, you can't resolve it. You have to create new windows.

Comment: So, I will have to make my main window to open another window - something like that? In other words, instead of using messageboxe, I will use new window that will look like messagebox? And btw thanks for the Win32GUI thing, helped me also a tons :)

Comment: yeah, make windows look like messageboxes but instead of making 'new' windows, you should make 'toplevels' of your main window.

Answer (score 0):

You also forgot to add the base option:

```
    setup(
        name = 'Kinetic Energy Calculator',
        version = '0.1',
        description = 'Calculate',
        executables = [Executable('calculator1.pyw', base="Win32GUI")]
        )
```

Although it still won't work, tkinter will now be recognized.